# ASSEMBLY EMU8086 - My program kind of mess up after getting some inputs?

Tags: assembly, emu8086

Here is my code to compare one-digit number inputs and print the greatest one

```
.MODEL SMALL
.DATA
PROMPT DB 10, 13, "Enter your number: $"
MAX_IS DB 10, 13, "Max number is: $"
NUM DB 0
MAX DB 0

.CODE
GET_INPUT PROC NEAR
          LEA DX, PROMPT   
          MOV AH, 9        
          INT 21H          
    
          MOV AH, 1        
          INT 21H          
          
          ; terminates if input is 0                
          CMP AL, 30H      
          JE TERMINATE     
                          
          MOV NUM, AL      
          CALL CMP_MAX     
          RET             
GET_INPUT ENDP            
                          
CMP_MAX PROC NEAR          
        MOV AL, MAX        
        CMP AL, NUM        
        JL SET_MAX         
        RET                
CMP_MAX ENDP              
.STARTUP                  
    MOV AX, @DATA          
    MOV DS, AX            
    MOV ES, AX            
                          
    CALL GET_INPUT                              
                          
SET_MAX:                  
    MOV AL, NUM            
    MOV MAX, AL            
    JMP GET_INPUT          
                          
TERMINATE:                
    LEA DX, MAX_IS         
    MOV AH, 9              
    INT 21H              
                          
    MOV DL, MAX          
    MOV AH, 2              
    INT 21H                

.EXIT
END
```

After entering some inputs, the program just went crazy. I read that the disadvantage of using `PROC` is that it takes the computer a small amount of time to link to the procedure and return
from it. Should I only use one `PROC` instead?

Comment: `JMP GET_INPUT` <-- Don't `JMP` to something that will `RET`; use `CALL`.

Comment: For blocks that you `jmp` between, just put them in the same PROC, even if it's after a `ret`.  They're not separate procedures, instead parts of the same function.  PROC or not doesn't change how they're laid out in memory, it's actually using `call` / `ret` (and following a standard calling convention for passing args) that the CPU actually has to do at run-time.

Comment: @Michael thanks! I'm new to this and I just realized how the flow of the program works when using ```PROC```.